# What is the difference between a collection of associations and a dictionary in Smalltalk?

Tags: dictionary, smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

```
| dict |
dict := #{'foo'->'brown'. 'bar'->'yellow'.
          'qix'->'white'. 'baz'->'red'. 'flub'->'green'} asDictionary.
dict at: 'qix'
```

If I `PrintIt`, I get 'white'. If I remove 'asDictionary', I still get 'white'. What does a dictionary give me that a collection of associations doesn't?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expression like `#{exp1 . sxp2 . exp3}` is [amber-smalltalk](/questions/tagged/amber-smalltalk)specific and creates a *HashedCollection*, which is a special kind of dictionary where keys are strings (probably in Javascript you use things like this a lot).

In other smalltalks there is no expression like that. Instead array expressions which look like: `{exp1 . sxp2 . exp3}` (there is no leading `#`) were introduced in [squeak](/questions/tagged/squeak) and are also available in [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) (which is a fork of Squeak) and Amber. Now the array expression creates an *Array* and so you have to use integers for `#at:` message. For example `dict at: 2` will return you an association `'bar'->'yellow'` because it is on the second position of the array you've created.

`#asDictionary` is a method of a collection that converts it into a dictionary given that the elements of the collection are associations. So if you want to create a dictionary with keys other than strings, you can do it like this:

```
dict := {
    'foo' -> 'brown'  .
        1 -> 'yellow' .
    3 @ 4 -> 'white'  .
   #(1 2) -> 'red' } asDictionary
```

Answer (score 4):

A `Dictionary` **is** a collection of `Association`s.  It is, in fact,  Smalltalk's canonical collection of Associations. (An instance of the Association Class is a key value pair, where the value can be an object of any Class).

**The advantage a Dictionary gives you is** that it has specialised methods for dealing with Associations, compared to other Collections you might be tempted to use.

A `Dictionary` provides:
 `removeKey: aKey    .` removes aKey
 `includesKey: aKey  .` checks for the existence of the key
 `includes: aValue   .` checks for the existence of a value
 `at:put:            .` shorthand for

```
anAssociation := Association key:value:   .
aDictionary add:
```

e.g.

```
anAssociation := Association key:   'Hello' 
                             value: 'A greeting people often use' .
aDictionary add: anAssociation .
```

If the key already exists in the Dictionary, then `at:put` will overwrite the pre-existing value with the new value, so it's important to check and make sure that the key has a unique value when adding new items.

Both the key and the value can be an object instance of any Class. Every Association in a Dictionary can be any kind of object, and every single key and value might be a instance of a different Class of object from every other element in the Dictionary.

You can create an Association by

```
anAssociation := Association key: 'keyOfElement' value: 'valueOfElement'
```

or, more succinctly,

```
anAssociation := 'keyOfElement' -> 'valueOfElement'
```

If you want to use keys entirely made specifically of `Symbol`s, there is also the `Class` `IdentityDictionary`

Comment: n.b. 
`{ } asDictionary` is not supported in Squeak, Dolphin Smalltalk or Amber.

It is a Pharo-specific convenience syntax, and works from at least Pharo 1.4 upwards.